# Overloading with Short and int

Tags: java

Why this code will print int?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    short s = 5;
    A(s);
}
public static void A(int a){
    System.out.println("int");
}

public static void A(Short a){
    System.out.println("short");
}
```

Comment: Any class are suitable. First - short, second - Short.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because upcasting to `int` was in version 1.0 of Java and auto-boxing was added in version 5.0.  Changing the behaviour would break code written for older version of Java.

However, mixing types like this suggests there is something wrong with your design, its only something you are going to find in puzzlers. ;)

Comment: This is a question of my colleague, who is preparing for certification.

Comment: If there were an interview question, I would suggest you just not write the code that way because its confusing. ;)

Answer (score 12):

Because widening beats boxing

**Reason:**

Because widening was there long long before where boxing was introduced later on so not to break any code it does this.

Comment: Also **widening beats var arg**