# How JVM finds method (parameter with the closest matching) to call in case of function overloading

Tags: java, types, jvm, overloading

The JVM decides which overloaded method to call at compile time.  I have one example:

```
public class MainClass{

  public static void go(Long n) {System.out.println("takes Long ");}
  public static void go(Short n) {System.out.println("takes Short ");}
  public static void go(int n) {System.out.println("takes int ");}

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    short y = 6;
    long z = 7;
    go(y);
    go(z);
    go((Short)y);
  }
}
```

According to my understanding, it should print the following:

```
takes Short
takes Long
takes Short
```

... but the actual output is:

```
takes int
takes Long
takes Short
```

However if I have the following three functions:

```
public static void go(Integer n) {System.out.println("takes Integer");}
public static void go(Long n) {System.out.println("takes Long ");}
public static void go(Short n) {System.out.println("takes Short ");}
```

... and call it using:

```
int a= 10; and go(i);  //output : takes Integer.
```

... why there is there a difference for `short` and `int`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/6268157/2087187

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [JLS Section 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), for rules compiler follows to determine which method to invoke. Compiler always chooses the most specific method in case your methods are overloaded:

> There may be more than one such method, in which case the most specific one is chosen. The descriptor (signature plus return type) of the most specific method is one used at run time to perform the method dispatch.

Compiler first tries to resolve the method without boxing or unboxing as quoted there:

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution **without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion**, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.

Emphasis mine.

So, in your 1<sup>st</sup> code, since *short* can be used as argument for parameter of type *int*. Compiler will not use the method with parameter `Short`, as that requires boxing. While in case of *long* type, since it cannot be used as argument for type *int*, it goes for boxing it to `Long`. Remember *Widening is preferred over Boxing*.

In your 2<sup>nd</sup>, there is no other way than boxing `int` to `Integer`. So, it calls method with `Integer` parameter.

Answer (score 9):

The JVM doesn't find it at all. The compiler does. It chooses the *most specific* method, following the rules in [JLS section 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.
>
> ... (full rules) ...

Comment: +1 not only must the name and parameters types be an exact match but the return type must be as well.  If you A calls B and you change the return type of a method in B without re-compiling A, it will fail to find the method at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Widening happens before boxing (if any). So `short` will become `int` and call that methods.

Besides, not directly relevant with this questions but interesting point: You cannot box and widen i.e. `short` can't become `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

Java looks for the closest match first. It tries to find the following:

1. Exact match by type
2. Matching a super class type
3. Converting to a larger primitive type
4. Converting to an auto boxed type
5. Varargs