# How do overloading methods decide on types in Java

Tags: java

Why does this treat 100 as an int? Why not as a byte or short?

```
System.out.print(100);
```

I read this somewhere:

> The compiler chooses the method that has the closest type of the argument in order of the implicit casting.

I don't understand what it means by "closest". Is it to do with the memory it takes in RAM or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How JVM finds method (parameter with the closest matching) to call in case of function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999480/how-jvm-finds-method-parameter-with-the-closest-matching-to-call-in-case-of-fu)

Comment: this isn't complicated, just read the `JLS`. it's not a very fun read, but will answer your question

Comment: I believe this has more to do with how the compiler interprets the literal `100` and not so much about method overloading. [Take a look at this SO answer about numeric literals in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193919). `100` is treated as an `int` even though it could technically fit in a `byte`.

Comment: I think integer literal in Java is int by default.

Comment: As `System.out.print(byte)` and `System.out.print(short)` don't exist, and as `100` isn't a byte or short literal, it is difficult to see how your confusion arises, or what you think this has to do with method overloading.

Comment: It's like MIKEC said: integer literals in Java are `int` by default and `long` if `int` can't store it.

Comment: @akuzminykh The last part of your comment isn't correct. An explicit '`L` is required.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, right. Thanks for pointing out.