# when overload same method display(String s ) and display(Object o) ,when pass null in method from main method why display(String s ) is called?

Tags: java

```
package polymorphism;
/*
 * @author Rahul Tripathi
 */
public class OverLoadingTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @return 
     */
    static void display(String s){
        System.out.println("Print String"); 
    }

    static void display(Object s){
        System.out.println("Print Object");                 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        OverLoadingTest.display(null);
    }

}
```

Output:

`Print String`

IN above program
when overload same method `display(String s )` and `display(Object o)` ,when pass `null` in method  from main method why `display(String s )` is called only. Why not called `display(Object o)`?

Comment: I am actually surprised it compiles rather than say "ambiguous method call".

Comment: IT is compiled code.IT will not say ambiguous method call.Please check it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java method dispatch with null argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377203/java-method-dispatch-with-null-argument)

Comment: @Zhuinden - It will compile :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overloading with Short and int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268157/overloading-with-short-and-int)

Answer (score 2):

Overloaded method is called on the basis of best/closest match. `Object` is the top level class, which means this will be matched at the last.  So matching starts with the method taking `String` parameter, as string can be `null` so it is matched and called.

Answer (score 1):

The most *non-generic* method among the *matching* methods will be selected.
i.e, `null` can be accepted as both *Object* as well as a *String* but Since String is also an Object, the compiler thinks that String has a higher probability of being null rather than an Object.

Answer (score 0):

Because overloadding will be happen with best closet match that is string and object is last closet one because all classes which are inherited from java.lang.object right, so that why it is happen

Answer (score 0):

In java when multiple overloaded methods are present, java looks for the closest match first. It tries to find the following:

1. Exact math by type
2. Matching a superclass type
3. Converting to a larger primitive type
4. Converting to an autoboxed type

So in your overloaded method String class is closets sub class of object class.