# method overloading int vs short

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

Following class has overloaded method `calculate`. First method accepts `int` and second one accepts `short`.

```
public class TestOverLoading
{
    public void calculate(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("int method called!");
    }

    public void calculate(short i)  //or byte
    {
        System.out.println("short method called!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //Test1
        new TestOverLoading().calculate(5); //int method called

        //Test2         
        new TestOverLoading().calculate((short) 5); //short method called
    }
}
```

Question is that how does `int method called!` gets printed on `Test1`? How it is determined that the 5 is `int` and not `short`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading with Short and int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268157/overloading-with-short-and-int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler makes this decision at compile time. It identifies the type of the provided arguments; and then it searches for the best match.

Thus: the type of 5 is int; therefore the compiles put a call to `calculate(int)` into the bytecode. Using the cast, you basically instruct the compiler to select `calculate(short)` instead.

The important thing to understand is that **overloading** is compile time only. This is different in language that support **dynamic dispatch** - in such languages, the "best fitting" type is determined at runtime. And as Seelenvirtuose is commenting: the whole idea of "OO design" and *polymorphism* is that **overriding** is dynamic! Thus it is important to clearly distinguish between the two; as overloading is compile-time; and overriding is run-time!

Comment: Java also has _dynamic dispatch_: method _overriding_ is resolved at runtime (hence, dynamic). But - you are right - method _overloading_ is completely resolved at compile time. +1

Comment: Thanks; I took your comment and added it to the answer!